# Should I Place My MySQL Database Connection Inside A PHP Function?

Tags: php, mysql, function

Is it safe to place my MySQL Database Connection inside a PHP Function so that other PHP functions can use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. it is a good idea.

I even place mine in a class.

```
class database {

     protected $databaseLink;

     function __construct($mysql_db, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_dbName){
            $this->databaseName = $mysql_dbName;
            $this->database = $mysql_db;
            $this->mysql_user = $mysql_user;
            $this->mysql_pass = $mysql_pass;
            $this->openConnection();
      }

      function openConnection(){
            $this->databaseLink = mysql_connect($this->database, $this->mysql_user, $this->mysql_pass);
            mysql_select_db($this->databaseName, $this->databaseLink);
      }

      function get_link(){
            return $this->databaseLink;
      }

}
```

Then you can just do:

```
 $db = new database('database', 'username', 'password', 'dbName');

 //to do a query:
 mysql_query("some query", $db->get_link());
```

Comment: Is there a procedural style method?

Comment: I also put such a file outside of the web root and include it where needed, so my credentials aren't spit out if one way or another the PHP isn't parsed.

Comment: @pNUT, so you might be reduced to using functions. is there a reason for not using OOP?

Comment: @Neal The majority of my code is in procedural style and I'm not really knowledgeable on OOP yet.

Comment: E.g., if your webroot is `/something/www/data/` I put the credentials in `/something/www/db_account.php` and then use something like `require('../db_account.php');` where I want to connect to my DB.

Comment: @pNUT, i showed you how to do it in my example. and its very useful. if you have a function that makes the connect all the time, that is alot of overhead on your part, (connecting to the mysql server) which i am sure you do not want

Comment: @Neal excuse the last comment please

Comment: @pNUT, so what do you want to know?

Comment: @pNUT, if OOP is your problem, then pop on the PHP chat room mate and ask :) I'm sure we'll be happy to point you in the right directions if you have any general OOP questions. The best thing to do is to get reading a little bit, and maybe check out and run some existing classes. Sometimes it's fun to pop onto something like phpclasses.org, download something (good) and then learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to create it in a regular PHP `function`.  If you will have multiple other functions accessing the db connection in the same script, remember that if you do something like

```
function get_db()
{
  $db = mysql_connect(...);
  return $db;
}
```

Then each time you call it, you will be creating and returning a new connection.  It may be better to create it once per script inside a class as a [Singleton](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php), and have a class method return the database one connection to any function that calls it.

**EDIT** Neal's answer actually demonstrates the singleton pattern for this nicely.  Beat me to it with a more code-complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good thing for performance. Connecting to the database just when the function was called it will result a good performance for SQL server.

Comment: emmmm what?    there could be many DB calls like that. that is never good